# Get a list of Images from an API and display every image in a list

Tags: c#, api, xaml, uwp

I'm using an API to fetch Json data, and i want to display every image from every card that i get from the collection, i can get the image URL from card.imageUrl, but the image source won't take a regular string. i tried to write card.imageUrl = String.Format(card.imageUrl) inside the foreach loop but it didn't work

XAML Code:

```
        <ListView Name="MasterListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind MagicCards}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Card">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{x:Bind ImageUrl}"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{x:Bind Name}" Foreground="{x:Bind Colors[0]}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Adding to the MagicCardsList

```
       public static async Task PopulateMagicCardsAsync(ObservableCollection<Card> magicCards)
    {
        var cardDataWrapper = await GetCardDataWrapperAsync();

        var cards = cardDataWrapper.cards;

        foreach (var card in cards)
        {
            if (card.Multiverseid.ToString() != null && card.Multiverseid.ToString() != "")
            {
                magicCards.Add(card);
            }
        }
    }
```

Main Page

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<Card> MagicCards { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        MagicCards = new ObservableCollection<Card>();       
    }
    private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyProgressRing.IsActive = true;
        MyProgressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        await MTGFacade.PopulateMagicCardsAsync(MagicCards);

        MyProgressRing.IsActive = false;
        MyProgressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Card Class

```
    public class Card
{
    [DataMember(Name = "imageUrl")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
```

EDIT: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5wmh.png

Comment: Can you please add the actual response from the API in your question?

Comment: Can you give an example URL?

Comment: Also, please explain what do you mean by: "i can get the image URL from card.imageUrl, but the image source won't take a regular string". What is your expected output and what is the output you see? Did you try to inspect an image element in developer's console and see if it had a valid image URL?

Comment: Change `<Image Source="{x:Bind ImageUrl}"/>` to `<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>` (and properly set the DataContext property). Now automatic type conversion from string to ImageSource will take place.

Comment: Or use a value converter, as explained in [Data binding in depth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth), section *What if the source and the target are not the same type?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `x:Bind` requires exactly matching types of the source and target property, `Binding` benefits from built-in automatic type conversion (here from `string` to `ImageSource`).

So change

```
<Image Source="{x:Bind ImageUrl}"/>
```

to

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
```